# Saving checkbox values into the sqlachemy database

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, bootstrap-5

Im new to flask and flask-sqlalchemy

Im currently working on website with checkboxes; but im getting an error. Here is the part of the code.

```
bodygoal= request.form.get('BodyGoal')
        workouttype= request.form.getlist('WorkoutType')
        slevel= request.form.get('SkillLevel')
        new_workout=Workout(bodygoalDB=bodygoal, workouttypeDB=workouttype, slevelDB=slevel, user_id=current_user.id)
        db.session.add(new_workout)
        db.session.commit()
```

as for the database model; here is also the part of the part of the code

```
class Workout(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bodygoalDB=db.Column(db.Integer)
    workouttypeDB=db.Column(db.String())
    slevelDB=db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

this is the error im getting:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO workout ("bodygoalDB", "workouttypeDB", "slevelDB", user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Shredded', ['on', 'Dumbell', 'Barbell'], 'Beginner', 1)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

the workouttype variables gets all the checkbox values from the website; currently, im planning to store them in 1 cell but Im also accepting suggestions on how to deal with checkbox values with sqlalchemy. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`request.form.getlist('WorkoutType')` is returning a list of strings, e.g. ['on', 'Dumbell', 'Barbell'], but you are trying to assign the list to column of data type string.

You could convert the string array to a comma delimited string:

```
# Get the string array
workout_types = request.form.getlist('WorkoutType')

# Convert to comma delimited string
workout_csv = ','.join(workout_types)

# etc
new_workout = Workout(bodygoalDB=bodygoal, workouttypeDB=workout_csv, slevelDB=slevel, user_id=current_user.id)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. My friend suggested another approach, he suggested to just make the equipments(barbell, dumbell) as database column. When the form is submitted; it checkboox values will be processed as boolean.